# Guid Validation in SQL

Tags: c#, sql

I am filtering the records in SQL through a GUID, if the Guid is empty then skip the filter but if it has some value, fetch the record based on filters.

I am using

```
WHERE USERID = IIF(@FILTERUSER IS NULL, AD.USERID, @FILTERUSER)
```

`UserId` and `FILTERUSER` are of type `uniqueidentifier`.

But it's not working. Kindly help.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by using `CAST(CAST(0 AS BINARY) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)` instead of `NULL`.

So the working code is:

```
WHERE USERID = IIF(@FILTERUSER = CAST(CAST(0 AS BINARY) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, AD.USERID, @FILTERUSER)
```